# Finding the sizeof structure

Tags: c, byte, structure, typedef, sizeof

What is the size (`sizeof(How_Many_Bytes)`) of the following structure, given the following machine 
parameters:

```
sizeof(char) == 1; sizeof(int) == 4; sizeof(long) == 8; sizeof(char *) == 8;
```

Integer values must be aligned.

```
typedef struct how_many_bytes { 
 long s; 
 char c, e; 
 int i; 
 char *d; 
} How_Many_Bytes;
```

I thought it would be 4+1+1+(2+4)+8 = 20 bytes but when I run on my machine I get 24 bytes. I wonder why?

Comment: google struct padding

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, what happens is this:

```
typedef struct how_many_bytes { 
 long s;          // 8   (NOT 4!)
 char c, e;       // 2
 char pad1, pad2; // 2 note these
 int i;           // 4 
 char *d;         // 8
} How_Many_Bytes; // 24 total
```

Some types have alignment requirements. Often on 4 or 8 byte boundaries.
So what the compiler does is to make the fields align on these boundaries
by added unnamed empty fields.

Comment: That's why I have (2+4).

Comment: Sizeof of long is 8, not4

Comment: You are right. It makes more sense now. Thanks.